# Programatically unzip an AES encrypted zip file on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, aes, unzip

I need to be able to unzip some AES (WinZip) encrypted zip files from within some C/C++ code on Windows. Has anybody got a way to do this?  I'm hoping for either some appropriate code or a DLL I can use (with an example usage). So far my searches have proved fruitless.

The commonly prescribed InfoZip libraries do not support AES encryption.

The best solution I have at the moment is calling the 7z.exe command line program from my program, but considering I'll be unzipping 100 files or so, this is less than ideal.

Comment: I don't post it as an answer because it's just a suggestion, but you could have a look in the 7z sources and see what zip library it uses. Since the whole thing is GPLed, it should use GPLed/LGPLed stuff also for "normal" zip decoding. Unfortunately, from what I saw, the zip compression code is not in the provided SDK (which is just for the 7z format), so you have to dig in the 7z *application* code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the minizip zlib contribution with AES support for both encryption and decryption.
https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip

Comment: This is the code I ended up using, as I was already using the minizip code. Some advice though: There are two places where the compiler tries to figure out the endian of your system (aesopt.h & sha1.c). It didn't work with the compiler I was using and took a while to figure out that was the problem. Recommend writing some test code around sha1.c to prove it produces expected results as a first step if the unzip doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: I have updated the aes library so it should fix the endian issues.

Comment: U may have to specify compression (degree) -9 to obtain a report in 7-zip stating AES-256 Deflate as property of the compressed file(entries).
The zip directory tree is not encrypted, i.e. the filenames are visible.
WAY simpler than using 7-zip libraries IMO.

Answer (score 0):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) can do it.  If you're not averse to using Managed C++.

From the [DotNetZip documentation](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/Code%20Examples/Cpp.htm), this is the code to *create* an AES Encrypted zip file. (The code to extract is similar).

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace Ionic::Zip;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");

    ZipFile ^ zip;
    try
    {
        zip = gcnew ZipFile();
        zip->Password = "Harbinger";
        zip->Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm::WinZipAes128;
        zip->AddEntry("Readme.txt", "This is the content for the Readme.txt entry.");
        zip->Save("test.zip");
    }
    finally
    {
        zip->~ZipFile();
    }

    Console::WriteLine(L"Press <ENTER> to quit.");
    Console::ReadLine();
    return 0;
}
```

Also - I wrote DotNetZip so I have a certain amount of favoritism toward it!  But I don't see what's wrong with exec'ing 7z.exe 100 times?  Are you concerned about performance?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.artpol-software.com/ZipArchive/ is the best choice.